# スプレッドシートの内容が書き換えられない件

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートの内容を書き換えたかったので、【スクリプトエディタ】をクリックして内容を書き換え、【change Color】を選んで【▶】をクリックしたところ、「承認が必要です」というメッセージが出たので【許可を確認】をクリックしましたら下記のメッセージが表示されました。

401. That's an error.
     Error : deleted_client
     The OAuth client was deleted.

確かにこのシートのスクリプトを書いた人間のアカウントは１ヶ月ほど前に削除いたしましたが、もうこのシートは内容を書き換えて使うことはできないのでしょうか。
ネットで調べましたが、よくわかりませんでした。（そもそも、OAuthの概念自体理解できません）
アカウントを削除する際、オーナー権限の譲渡は行なったのですが、OAuthのことは知りませんでした。
何かよい方法があれば、お教えください。
私はかなりこういったことに疎い人間ですので、できるだけ平易な言葉でご説明いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

[【G Suite】API接続情報を変更する](https://cg-support.isr.co.jp/hc/ja/articles/360011350594) の記事のケース２に該当する状況だと思われます。

上記の記事に対応方法の説明があるので、参考にされては如何でしょうか。